# Capture the dialog between sendmail and SMTP server

Tags: perl, email, smtp, sendmail

My objective is to verify undeliverables on the fly and update my database accordingly when sending emails.

I am using `sendmail` like so

```
open(MAIL, "|$sendmail -oi -t -v");
print MAIL "From: $from\n";
```

In verbose mode I get all the feedback from the remote server and can see the return codes when the recipient is not recognised. Unfortunately I have been unable to capture this text.

I have tried [`Capture::Tiny`][Capture::Tiny] with no success. The output prints to the screen and the capture variable is empty.

I have tried [`Mail::Sender`][Mail::Sender] with no success. It returns an OK response even when the recipient is undeliverable.

I have tried all the commonly used techniques of redirecting `STDOUT` but sendmail always prints to the screen and my capture variable is always empty.

I have tried [`Net::SMTP`][Net::SMTP] with no success. `$smtp->message()` does not return any information that would allow me to identify undeliverables.

I have queried `$?` after printing to `sendmail`, but it always has a zero value.

If I could capture the dialogue between `sendmail` and the remote SMTP server, I could parse it and identify undeliverables.

Has anyone done this with success, and if so, how?

**Afternote**

I am aware that there are many reasons why a mail may not be delivered and it may take hours before a definitive response can be obtained. However the vast majority of my undeliverables are simply recipient not recognised and these can be handled immediately. This is what I am trying to do.

**Edit**

I have continued working on this and have added the following code:

```
open(SAVEOUT, ">&STDOUT");
open(SAVEERR, ">&STDERR");
close(STDOUT);
close(STDERR);
open(STDOUT, '>', \$output) or die $!;
open(STDERR, ">&STDOUT") or die $!;
print "error\n";
print STDOUT "out\n";
open(MAIL, "|$sendmail -oi -t -v");
print MAIL "From: $from\n";
[...]
close( MAIL);
```

After closing MAIL, $output contains 'error' and 'out'. But id does not contain the output of sendmail, which no longer displays in the terminal because STDERR has been redirected. So the contents of $output demonstrate that STDERR has been redirected, the absence of sendmail output in the terminal demonstrates that sendmail is writing to STDERR, but we still can't capture the output from sendmail!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 open(MAIL, "|$sendmail -oi -t -v -v");
 print MAIL "From: $from\n";

 # redirect your script to get  all messages.
```

Comment: I put all the sendmail code in a separate file called sendemail.pl. Then I called that code like this: my $res = readpipe( "./sendemail.pl \"$from\" \"$subject\" \"$to\" \"$bcc\" \"$errorsto\" \"$body\"" ); it sends the email but I still don't capture the output. What am I missing? When I call readpipe( 'ls' ) I can capture the output. But not with sendmail. ???

Comment: I'm making progress. When I do this:

        $res = readpipe( "./sendemail.pl \"$from\" \"$subject\" \"$to\" \"$bcc\" \"$errorsto\" \"$copyofbody\" > log.txt 2>&1" );

I find that the output redirects to log.txt.

Now how do I get it into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can find is to redirect STDOUT to a file, then redirect STDERR to STDOUT and finally read the file into a variable which I then use.

Bizarrely, when I redirect to a variable instead of a file, only STDOUT gets redirected but not STDERR.